# Add Full Control Admin for site collection (Sharepoint online)

Tags: sharepoint-online

How Can I Add a new Admin for a site collection with full control using powershell  (sharepoint online)?

I used : `Set-SPOUser -site $Site -LoginName $AdminName -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $True` but it doesn't add the user as admin with full control.

Comment: That command only adds a site collection administrator, not a global administrator.

Answer (score 3):

The term "Global Admin" doesn't exist in a SharePoint Online Site Collection. According to the page [About Office 365 admin roles](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/about-office-365-admin-roles-da585eea-f576-4f55-a1e0-87090b6aaa9d), the Global Administrator role is the following:

> Accesses all administrative features in the Office 365 suite of
>   services in your plan, including Skype for Business. By default the
>   person who signs up to buy Office 365 becomes a global admin.

A Site Collection Administrator in a SharePoint Online Site Collection have full control of the entire Site Collection, which I guess is what you want to accomplish.

But if this i wrong, and you really want to add a Global Admin to the Office 365 tennant, then you need to navigate to the [Office 365 Admin center](https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home). Select **Users**, and on the **Active users** page, choose the one you want to make Global Admin. Selection of user bring up the user properties page. Edit roles and select Global Administrator and save. That's it (if you have the right permissions).

See [Assign admin roles in Office 365 for business](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-admin-roles-in-office-365-for-business-eac4d046-1afd-4f1a-85fc-8219c79e1504?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)